# Block access to /admin on secondary sites

Tags: control-panel, multi-site

I'm not clear on how to block access to the control panel at:
secondDomain.com/admin
secondDomain.com/admin/login

I can use .htaccess or Craft's config.php.

I want folks to get an ugly 'access denied' server msg when they try.

I only want the control panel to load at primaryDomain.com/admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Apache, you can use a [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) with the [F flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f) to deny any matching request with a HTTP 403 response. Use [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to apply your rule only to specific domains, or everything *but* that specific domain in your case. Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?primaryDomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?admin - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Long live [F]!!